# How to build & deploy Keter for NixOS?

Tags: haskell, nixos, keter

Here is my fork of Keter with `*.nix` files generated via `cabal2nix`: https://github.com/bsima/keter/tree/nix

I did `nix-build shell.nix` on my dev machine (NixOS 17.09), then used `nix-copy-closure` to put it on my VPS on Digital Ocean (also NixOS 17.09, via nix-infect).

I created a systemd service which starts just fine, but then Keter dies after trying to fork a process for the server:

```
2018-02-03 19:34:03.21: Data.Conduit.Process.Unix.monitorProcess: /opt/keter/temp/pprjam-0/dist/bin/pprjam: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

It can't find `exec`, which I believe should be a part of `coreutils`. I doubt `coreutils` is missing, but just in case I put it in my `environment.systemPackages` and rebuilt, but it still didn't work.

So that makes me think this is a `$PATH` problem, or [this issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/17267) (which I don't quite understand, so I'm assuming it's more likely a `$PATH` problem).

Is there something I have to do in Keter's `default.nix` in order to help it find `exec` on the `$PATH` of the target machine? What else am I missing here?

Comment: Note that I added a keter module to nixpkgs, it's available in all unstable and future releases, please try it out!
https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=unstable&show=services.keter.enable&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=keter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` is actually a shell built-in, not a `coreutils` command. Actually the createProcess error message is confusing. The command name that can't be found comes before the `createProcess:`. So the problem is not that `pprjam` can not find `exec` (as a command), but `createProcess` detected a failed `exec` system call.

It seems that `/opt/keter/temp/pprjam-0/dist/bin/pprjam` is missing on your server, or the runtime linker can not find `pprjam`'s dependencies. If the latter is the case, you may be able to fix it by extending the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable of the Keter service.

Comment: Ooh, that makes sense. `pprjam` depends on `libpqxx`, but can't find it. I guess I just need to use `nix-copy-closure` to deploy `pprjam` and setup nginx as a frontend webserver instead of keter.

Comment: That's probably a better solution. Although keter is quite simple, it expect it to provide little benefit. Its killer feature, zero-downtime redeploys, can also be achieved with systemd socket activation.

Comment: Zero-downtime redeploys was what I wanted it for most of all. I'm not familiar with "systemd socket activation" but I will research it, thanks!